# rsync synchronizing files only without creating folders on destination

Tags: backup, rsync, files, directory

Is it possible with rsync to not create directories on destination?

MY SOURCE:

```
a/
a/x.txt
b/
b/y.txt
b/c/g.txt
```

MY WANTED DESTINATION:

```
d/x.txt
d/y.txt
d/g.txt
```

Is there any way to do this with RSYNC?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, iff file names are all unique, and you know the list of directories in advance:

```
rsync -v -dm -lptgo a/ b/ b/c/ d
```

(Slashes after directory names are important.)